# JTable add File object, but only display File Name

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a Java application which uses JTables to add files for browsing. It contains only 1 column:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Name"}, 0);

    JTable tracks = new JTable(model){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int collIndex){
            return false;
        }
    };

tracks.addMouseListener(new PopupListener());

tracks.setShowGrid(false);
```

Adding files to the table is done like this:

```
for (File file : results){
    model.addRow(new Object[] {file});
}
```

I need to add the actual file, not just its name because I will use it later. However, is it possible that the table shows only the file name (file.getName();) instead of the entire path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ..is it possible that the table shows only the file name (file.getName();) instead of the entire path?

It sure is.  Use a [`TableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) to show just the name.  See [How to Use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for details.

See also the [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for general tips (like using the icon for the file).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, overriding the Default Renderer worked perfectly :)